# Using salesforce APEX code I want to retrieve data from Kafka using rest API

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apex

I am working on one task where I need to retrieve data from Kafka to Salesforce using Rest API.

I am aware of Salesforce HTTPRequest and HTTPResponse but, I am not aware of Kafka

Comment: Are you having issues writing a Kafka consumer and using the Salesforce API?

Comment: Having an issue in writing a Kafka consumer. I want to write a Kafka consumer in Apex.

Comment: Sure, can you edit your question to include the code you've tried?

Comment: Actually, I have found sample code for Kafka consumer for java but, I did not find a code for salesforce. 
Actually did not know about hostname, Endpoint URL, the authentication method for authentication do that I have not done any code. I also do not know which parameters are required for the authentication method.

Can you please provide a simple code Kafka authentication.

Comment: I believe the Apache or Confluent documentation provides SSL and SASL connection examples, but I don't have direct links

Answer (score 0):

There is a [REST Proxy](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest) for Kafka, which enables you to retrieve (and send) data from Kafka using HTTP REST calls.